# Large volume options sell

Tags: options, trading-volume

In Casino Royale, the villain trades put options worth USD 100 million and loses. My question is say if he had won, would he have been able to sell the USD 100 million worth of options? Say option price at buy was $1.00 per contract. He would have had to sell a million contracts.

Is the options marker for stock trading that big per stock? Realistically what is the typical dollar amount and volume in dollar amount can one expect to trade for a stock for a PARTICULAR strike price? Can this go to 10s of millions of dollars?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon who the counterparty is.

If the counterparty is the OCC, they would most likely call force majeure if their finances were at serious risk.  They could be forced to take a loss but not to be pulled apart.  Villain could always try to take the OCC to court, but then his plot would probably be exposed in discovery.

The need to involve the courts is even greater if these are private contracts.

If the options were on one security, they would be difficult to sell in one day.  If they were spread across the most liquid ETFs and equities, they could be sold in one day easily, the above solvency problems notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in the most liquid securities, but currently it would take several days to get filled in one contract at that amount

There are also position size limits (set by the OCC and other Self Regulatory Organizations) that attempt to prevent people from cornering a market through the options market. (getting loads of contacts without effecting the price of the underlying asset, exercising those contracts and suddenly owning a huge stake of the asset and nobody saw it coming - although this is still VERY VERY possible)

So for your example of an option of $1.00 per contract, then the position size limits would have prevented 100 million of those being opened (by one person/account that is).

Realistically, you would spread out your orders amongst several options strike prices and expiration dates.

Stock Indexes are some very liquid examples, so for the Standard & Poors you can open options contracts on the SPY ETF, as well as the S&P 500 futures, as well as many other S&P 500 products that only trade options and do not have the ability to be traded as the underlying shares.

And there is also the saying "liquidity begets liquidity", meaning that because you are making the market more liquid, other large market participants will also see the liquidity and want to participate, where they previously thought it was too illiquid and impossible to close a large position quickly